# Скопировать папку или несколько файлов при удаленной отладке

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, отладка

Как для удаленной отладки настроить автоматическое копирование папок или нескольких файлов перед стартом. В настройках удаленной отладки есть параметер `Additional Files To Deploy`, когда я указываю в нем путь к нужной папке, то страрт отладки остановливается с ошибкой:

> Error: Unable to deploy local file 'указанный путь'

Не работают шаблонные символы "звездочки" и "вопросы", то есть если указать например `\my\super\files\*` или `\my\super\files\*.data`. Когда указываю путь к одному файлу все работает. Также работет если указать несколько явных путей к файлам через точку с запятой, например `\my\debug\file\first.data;\my\debug\files\second.data`, и так далее. Но этот последний способ требует знать заранее какие файлы содержаться в папке, а во-вторых неудобен при большом количестве файлов.

Так вот, как настроить параметер `Additional Files To Deploy` для удаленного разворачивания нескольких файлов и/или папок?

Comment: А если * туда вместо имени файла?

Comment: Звездочки не работают

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать такой wildcard: `/my/super/files/**/*` Он должен соответствовать всем файлам и папкам в `/my/super/files` любой вложености.

Comment: Так не работает, выдает то же самое.

Comment: какая у вас версия Visual Studio?

Comment: У меня стоит VS 2017